# how to change the row color in jquery dataTable based on the value

Tags: jquery, django, datatables

I am using the DataTable in javascript and jquery  in order to setup a interactive table. I want to change the row color based on cell value.

I tried to use the **fnRowCallback** function and i tried to use **rowCallback** function.

in both functions are not working and the page is not displaying the table.

if i remove these functions the table is displayed and all data are available.

```
 $(function(){

        var destsData=[
        ]
        var sections={}
        var theTable = $('#SearchT2chiraTable').DataTable({
            language: {
                search: 'ﺑﺤﺚ : ',
                lengthMenu:'ﻣﺸﺎﻫﺪﺓ _MENU_ ﺑﻴﺎﻧﺎﺕ',
                paginate: {
                    first:      "اﻻﻭﻝ",
                    previous:   "اﻟﺴﺎﺑﻖ",
                    next:       "اﻟﺘﺎﻟﻲ",
                    last:       "اﻻﺧﻴﺮ"
                }
            },
            select: 'single'
        })
        var destsTable = $('#DestsTable').DataTable({    
            "fnRowCallback": function(nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull){
                if ( aData[2] == "DEFAULT VALUE" )
                {
                    $('td', nRow).css('background-color', 'red' );
                }
                else
                {
                    $('td', nRow).css('background-color', 'white');
                }

            language: {
                search: 'ﺑﺤﺚ : ',
                lengthMenu:'ﻣﺸﺎﻫﺪﺓ _MENU_ ﺑﻴﺎﻧﺎﺕ',
                paginate: {
                    first:      "اﻻﻭﻝ",
                    previous:   "اﻟﺴﺎﺑﻖ",
                    next:       "اﻟﺘﺎﻟﻲ",
                    last:       "اﻻﺧﻴﺮ"
                }
            },

            select: 'single',
            data: destsData,
            columns: [
                { "data": "destination_id","title":'اﻟﺮﻣﺰ' },
                { "data": "te2chira_id_id","title":'ﺭﻣﺰ اﻟﺘﺄﺷﻴﺮﺓ' },
                { "data": "opinion", "title": 'اﻻﻗﺘﺮاﺡ' },
                { "data": "destination_date","title":'اﻟﺘﺎﺭﻳﺦ' },

                { "data": "section","title":'اﻟﻘﻄﻌﺔ' ,

                        "render":function(val,type,row,meta){
                            console.log('the Value is ',val)
                            if (type == 'set'){
                                console.log('doing here ')
                                row.section = val
                                row.section_display=sections[row.section]
                                row.section_filter=sections[row.section]
                                return
                            }else if (type === 'display',val) {
                                console.log('display')
                                return sections[val];
                            }
                            else if (type === 'filter') {
                                console.log('filter',val)
                                return row.section_filter;
                            }
                            // 'sort', 'type' and undefined all just use the integer
                            return row.section;
                        }
                    }


             ]
           }
        });
```

or  the second function.

```
"rowCallback": function( row, data, index ) {

                if ( data.opinion == "DEFAULT VALUE" )
                {
                    $('td', row).css('background-color', 'Red');
                }
                else
                {
                    $('td', row).css('background-color', 'white');
                }

            }
           }
```

i expect to display the data in  the **destTable** and where the opinion has a value equal to **DEFAULT VALUE** to make the row color red  else to keep it white.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fnRowCallback` feels like the right way to do this, but I notice you're missing a closing curly brace and a comma - which will cause your code to break and not render the table.

```
"fnRowCallback": function(nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull){
    if ( aData[2] == "DEFAULT VALUE" )
    {
        $('td', nRow).css('background-color', 'red' );
    }
    else
    {
        $('td', nRow).css('background-color', 'white');
    }
},  // Make sure you add the closing brace and a comma
language: {
...
```

Comment: this was the error thank you. but i needed to specify the field name and the index of the field.

Answer (score 0):

You can this in another way

```
{% for q in queryset %}

   {% if q.id == 1 %}
     <tr style="background: #fff;>
   {% else %}
     <tr style="background: #000;>
   {% endif %}
        <td></td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: i tried your answer  where i add it inside the created table above the javascript code but it did not work.

code:

`<table id="DestsTable" class="searchte2chira" >
    {% for row in tableItems %}

       {% if row.opinion == "DEFAULT VALUE" %}
         <tr style="background: #fff;>
       {% else %}
         <tr style="background: #000;>
       {% endif %}
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>`